# Selenium how to click age verification with no link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Error results because I am unable to obtain the correct element through xpath.
Has the web handle changed? 
Can I click an image? I don't understand how to interpret the error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#browser.get('https://ebs.lcb.state.pa.us/OA_HTML/AppsLocalLogin.jsp')
driver.get('http://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com')
assert 'Fine Wine & Good Spirits: Shop Online for Wine and Spirits in Pennsylvania' in driver.title

browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath=//div[@id='ageVerify']/img[@alt='Yes']").click()
```

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate
>   an element with the xpath expression
>   xpath=//div[@id='ageVerify']/img[@alt='Yes'] because of the following
>   error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The
>   result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the
>   desired type.   (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.26.436362
>   (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: First off, update your question with the HTML snipped where the element you're targeting resides. Secondly, use a different `WebElement` locator. Open your browser console and start using jQuery to validate if your selector is valid (e.g.: `$x(//div[@id='ageVerify']/img[@alt='Yes'])`, or `$(div#ageVerify img[alt="Yes"])` for CSS-path). Your error cannot be more verbose than that. (`Unable to locate an element with the xpath exp...`, which translates to, your selector's not good)

Answer (score 0):

There's another div in between the div and img in your Xpath, so your Xpath isn't returning anything.

Change `"xpath=//div[@id='ageVerify']/img[@alt='Yes']"` to `"//div[@id='ageVerify']/div/img[@alt='Yes']"` and you should be able to click it.

Comment: It's the in-between div that has the onclick() event to close the popup window; not the image itself.  Clicking on the image might not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are using driver `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
to initiate the webdriver and browser`browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath=//div[@id='ageVerify']/img[@alt='Yes']").click()` to click on image which is not correct, you have to use single variable for the code to continue.

There are three images on popup

1. Welcome to finewineandgoodspirits"
2. Yes
3. No

Since you want to click on Yes to continue on site, you need to update the xpath code to click on Yes image

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ageVerify']//img[@alt='Yes']").click()
```

I have used this code and I was able to click on Yes image

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com')
assert 'Fine Wine & Good Spirits: Shop Online for Wine and Spirits in Pennsylvania' in driver.title
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ageVerify']//img[@alt='Yes']").click()
```

Comment: Sorry for the error with driver / browser. I did not correct it before posting. I can't believe I actually had it correct except for that. Thank you for helping!